# bash dialog read variables from form

Tags: bash, dialog

Let's say I got dialog defined like this:

```
dialog --backtitle "Dialog Form Example" --title "Dialog - Form" \
--form "\nDialog Sample Label and Values" 25 60 16 \
"Form Label 1:" 1 1 "Value 1" 1 25 25 30 \
"Form Label 2:" 2 1 "Value 2" 2 25 25 30 \
"Form Label 3:" 3 1 "Value 3" 3 25 25 30 \
"Form Label 4:" 4 1 "Value 4" 4 25 25 30
```

That would show 4 inputs... but how do I read the output of that in bash script?

`$?` seems to output `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to assign the different form fields to different var's, you need to parse the output.

```
ans=$(dialog --backtitle "Dialog Form Example" --title "Dialog - Form" \
--form "\nDialog Sample Label and Values" 25 60 16 \
"Form Label 1:" 1 1 "Value 1" 1 25 25 30 \
"Form Label 2:" 2 1 "Value 2" 2 25 25 30 \
"Form Label 3:" 3 1 "Value 3" 3 25 25 30 \
"Form Label 4:" 4 1 "Value 4" 4 25 25 30 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
echo -e "\n\n\n\nAnswer=[${ans}]"
i=0
while read -r line; do
   ((i++))
   declare var$i="${line}"
done <<< "${ans}"
echo "var2=${var2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the standard output of **dialog** to a variable:

```
RESULTS=$(dialog --backtitle "Dialog Form Example" --title "Dialog - Form" \
--form "\nDialog Sample Label and Values" 25 60 16 \
"Form Label 1:" 1 1 "Value 1" 1 25 25 30 \
"Form Label 2:" 2 1 "Value 2" 2 25 25 30 \
"Form Label 3:" 3 1 "Value 3" 3 25 25 30 \
"Form Label 4:" 4 1 "Value 4" 4 25 25 30)
```

In such a way, all the values will be there.

https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_form_dialog_for_input